# How to encode [CLLocation] properly in swift?

Tags: swift3, encode, cllocation

I am doing an application which need to store the user's data in local. I read the documentation in Apple website, it covers part of the info in how to encode basic type, such as String and Int. However, when I try to encode with the [CLLocation]type, it failed. I am asking if some expert can give me any hint on how to encode such type in Swift?

Here is my code about the Model class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import os.log
import CoreData

//route model
//store the model in the local database.
//change all the [CLLocations] to become the String inorder to store it in local.???? not willing
class Route:  NSObject, NSCoding {
    //MARK: Properties
     var name :String
     var area : String
     var image: UIImage?
     var date : DispatchTime
     var routePoints = [CLLocation]()
     var rating: Int

     //MARK: Achieving paths
    //static properties, belong to the
    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Routes")

    //MARK: NSCoding
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(image, forKey: PropertyKey.image)
        aCoder.encode(date, forKey: PropertyKey.date)
        aCoder.encode(area, forKey: PropertyKey.area)
        //unable to encode the [cllocation]
        aCoder.encode(routePoints, forKey: PropertyKey.routePoints)
        aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
    }
    //should also added in the locations as one of the variable.
    init?(Name: String, Area: String, Date: DispatchTime, Image: UIImage?, RoutePoints: [CLLocation], Rating: Int) {
        guard (Rating >= 0) && (Rating <= 5) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = Name
        self.area = Area
        self.image = Image
        self.date = Date
        self.routePoints = RoutePoints
        self.rating = Rating
    }



    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        //this is the necessary property
        //these are optional properties
        let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
       guard   let date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.date) as? DispatchTime,
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String,
        let image = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.image) as? UIImage,
        let area = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.area) as? String,
        let routePoints = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.routePoints) as? [CLLocation] else{
            print("Unable to decode")
            return nil
        }
        self.init(Name: name, Area: area, Date: date, Image: image, RoutePoints: routePoints, Rating: rating)

    }



    //MARK: Types
    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let image = "image"
        static let date = "date"
        static let area = "area"
        static let rating = "rating"
        static let routePoints = "routePoints"
    }


}
```

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that CLLocation can't be stored with NSCoder.  You could implement a simple coder / decoder using a swift map for this type of value to basically store the locations in a dictionary.

```
let p1 = CLLocation(latitude: 1, longitude: 1)
let p2 = CLLocation(latitude: 2, longitude:2)

var locations = [p1, p2]

let codedArray = locations.map{ ["lat":$0.coordinate.latitude, "long":$0.coordinate.longitude] }
let decodedArray = codedArray.map{ CLLocation(latitude:$0["lat"]!, longitude:$0["long"]!) }
```

Comment: Hello, but after trying , it still doesn't work. Should I encode the codeArray?